# PythonWin opening different scripts in different versions (Python 2 & Python 3)

Tags: python, windows, version, multiple-instances

I use PythonWin as my main script editor.

To differentiate between scripts I use different extensions, *.py for Python 2 scripts and *.py3 for Python 3 scripts.
I have each extension opening in its appropriate version of PythonWin.exe through the HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT registry entries, so that's fine.
The problem is whenever I have PythonWin.exe version 2 running and I click on a *.py3 file it opens my script in the currently open version 2 version of PythonWin.  Similarly if I have version 3 open and I open a *.py file it opens in the currently open version 3 PythonWin.

I am wondering if anyone else has had this issue and whether they have found any kind of descent work-around so each file extension opens in their respective version of PythonWin.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out PythonWin.exe has some passable arguments to allow it to open more than one instance.
You can force it to open a new process by using the command

```
"C:\python27\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\Pythonwin.exe" /new "%L"
```

Using this as the opening command in the registry entries for .py and .py3 would open each in their respective version of PythonWin.
The only disadvantage is that each time you open a new file, it will open a new PythonWin instance.
/new will also disable any Dynamic Data Exchange(Windows uses this to communicate between open applications) so the instance of PythonWin will never open any new files opened from Windows Explorer within it.
Once you have an instance open, you may as well just use the "Open" filemenu option to open new files, or just have multiple instances of each version of PythonWin open.

Answer (score 0):

The thing in pythonwin.exe that looks for an existing instance and opens a *.py file in that instance is a protocol called a DDE(Dynamic Data Exchange) server.  PythonWin opens one up every time it runs and when it detects a DDE server on the same channel, it passes the previous instance some python code to open the file and then terminates.

The easiest way to prevent PythonWin 2.7 from talking to PythonWin 3.9 is to have them open separately named channels to talk on.

Change the channel name in the **intpyapp.py** file.

Look for these two functions

```
def MakeExistingDDEConnection(self):
and
def InitDDE(self):
```

Change the channel name from **"Pythonwin"** to **"Pythonwin37"**(or something) *IN BOTH FUNCTIONS*

Delete any "intpyapp.pyc" files from your computer and try it out! You'll love it.
(*.pyc files store a compiled version of the code in the *.py file so no changes will be made to the running code until these are deleted)

If that still doesn't work, check out what command line is being used to run pythonwin.exe in the Windows registry

```
\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.File\shell\open\command
```

and make sure there's no /new or /nodde parameters in the command line.
Here's an example of a good registry entry

```
"C:\python37\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\Pythonwin.exe" "%L"
```